# PHP sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have the following code to export data from MsSQL to Excel file, but it's throwing the following error:

> sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource ...

I've already installed the MSSQL Drivers, the connection string is working, all the Select, Updates queries are working as well...

```
$query = "
   SELECT * 
   FROM ativos 
   INNER JOIN colaboradores ON ativos.id_colaborador = colaboradores.id_colaborador 
   ORDER BY id_ativo DESC
";

$result = sqlsrv_query($connect, $query);

if (sqlsrv_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
   $output .= '
   <table class="table" bordered="1">  
   <tr>  
   <th>Ativo</th>  
   <th>Comentario</th>  
   <th>Data_Aquisicao</th>
   <th>Localizacao</th>
   <th>Fabricante</th>  
   <th>Modelo</th>  
   <th>IMEI</th>  
   <th>Nr de Serie</th>
   <th>Ativo_SAP</th>
   <th>Evento</th>  
   <th>Data_Evento</th>  
   <th>Colaborador</th>
   </tr>
   ';
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $output .= '
      <tr>  
      <td>'.$row["ativo"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["comentario"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["data_aquisicao"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["localizacao"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["fabricante"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["modelo"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["imei"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["numero_serie"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["ativo_sap"].'</td> 
      <td>'.$row["evento"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["data_evento"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["nome"].'</td>
      </tr>
      ';
   }
```

Comment: Usually that error message has a second part, specifically what type was given, such as `sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`. Do you have that?

Comment: @ChrisHaas `sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <PATH> on line 14` Line 14 is `$result = sqlsrv_query($connect, $query);`

Comment: Okay, so you'll want to inspect `$connect` because PHP says it is a string when instead it needs to be the result of calling [`sqlsrv_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Comment: As others mention, have you actually created a connection? 
`$srv = "server\instance"; $info = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password"); $connection = sqlsrv_connect($srv, $info);`.

Comment: @stuart I'm actually using PDO

Comment: @CarlosSantiago That is not obvious from your question. It seems you need a valid connection regardless.

Comment: @CarlosSantiago Please, post your full code (where you make a connection). Another issue here is the fact, that `sqlsrv_num_rows` requires (as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-num-rows?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)) _a client-side, static, or keyset cursor, and will return false if you use a forward cursor or a dynamic cursor. (a forward cursor is the default.)_.